# Http Post Request gives inconsistent results between Java 7 & Java 8 for same exact piece of code

Tags: java-8, java-7

Below is the piece of code that compiled and executed using `Java 7` gives results that are different from what I get with `Java 8`.

Tried with apache `httpclient` before going Native. I assume with other libraries issue would be the same

Output Jdk7

`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}`
   `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: XXX`
          ``` at ``sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627) ```

Output Jdk8 : **Expected Results**

```
public String requestSFAuthToken(Map<String, String> sfAttributes) throws Exception{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();        
    String request = sfAttributes.get("url");
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    OutputStreamWriter writer  = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "application/json"); 
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    conn.connect();
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(getParameters(sfAttributes));
    writer.flush();
    String line;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        result.append(line);
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close(); 
    conn.disconnect();
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(conn != null){
            String error ; 
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
            while ((error = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }finally{
        if(conn != null){
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        if(writer != null){
            writer.close();
        }
        if(reader != null){
            reader.close(); 
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}

private String getParameters(Map<String, String> sfAttributes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String params = URLEncoder.encode("grant_type", "UTF8")
            + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(sfAttributes.get("grant_type"), "UTF8");
    params += "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("client_id","UTF8")
            + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(sfAttributes.get("client_id"), "UTF8");
    params += "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("client_secret", "UTF8")
            + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(sfAttributes.get("client_secret"), "UTF8");
    params += "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8")
            + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(sfAttributes.get("username"), "UTF8");
    params += "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF8")
            + "="+ URLEncoder.encode(sfAttributes.get("password"), "UTF8");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: what are the results? ...

Comment: Added output results. With jdk8 I receive expected response.

Comment: Can you use a packet sniffer to examine all the differences in the request, including any cookies, other header differences, character encoding of the request?

Comment: @Dave I didn't yet but I just tried executing with `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties` option and `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL` in JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\logging.properties expecting raw HTTP to be printed on console without success.

Comment: Will try windump and see. Thx @Dave

Comment: It's a TLS version issue. The server does not support TLSv1.0 which is the default in Jdk7.